# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't know what is my problem but before, this works fine. So I have this Activity class MainMapActivity

```
public class MainMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_nav);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

**activity_main_nav**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and the included **activity_main_map**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Can somebody help me with my problem? I badly need some answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once came across an issue like this and I added a name attribute on the fragment in XML.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="com.testing.svma.MainActivity"/>
```

Might solve the issue.

Also please check the following:

1. Check your manifest for required permissions for maps
2. Make sure that meta data is right

Hope this helps.

**P.S:** The issue might also be with API level or the play services version.

Comment: hi @san I already tried to run my project from another device which I don't change any of my codes. And it successfully runs on Samsung Android version 5.1.1. But my phone is an Asus with and Android version also of 5.1.1 why is that when I run my app on Asus it shows that error. But on the other brand of phone with an Android version of 4.4.2 it does run successfully too.

Comment: Do you, by any chance knows why I encountered that error?

Comment: Android works in mysterious ways,each and every device manufacturer overlay their edit on the Google's virgin OS so as to create their own version of OS and some might be too shabby in their work. That might be the reason for the weird behavior. I will be able to help you more if you can send me the full stack trace...